# Windows Automation - getting text from an application running in Windows

Tags: windows, automation

I'd like to write a program that automatically gets the text an application is displaying in a window in Windows, and then analyses this text.

What would be the best approach to take? Ideally using Python, but I'm happy with any approach that works.

I've been researching automated Windows testing frameworks, but the ones I've looked at simply use screenshots to compare the output. I need to the program to get the text output and send an alert if certain products and prices are being displayed.

All suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have a complete code example, this is how I tackle such a problem (typically with python as well):

1) Find [a Microsoft article detailing what I'd like to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301438.aspx). (This is for text in an edit box, but you *should* be able to use similar methods for displayed text.

2) Determine what calls you need, and see if they are possible through python libraries. For Windows, you're typically looking at os, [win32api](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), and perhaps even WMI. Your best bet is to install these libraries, learn how to use them, and give what you're trying out a shot.